# Give access to bigquery tables with specific tables names, to be created in future, across all datasets in a gcp project?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I've searched the documentation a lot, but couldn't find anything that allows me to do the following:

Allow creating a role which allows full table access to tables with certain table names only (ex.: "table1", etc.) that'll be created in future. This should work across all available datasets in a GCP project, and also the ones that'll be created in future.

Is this possible? If not directly, indirectly maybe?

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do that would be to create a dataset for housing such tables, and set the access appropriate to what you need.  Tables requiring a different set of policies should be housed in other datasets.

More information here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/dataset-access-controls